# integrating independent ontology into UIMA based cTAKES

Tags: java, ontology, uima, ctakes

Okay, so basically, I have a cTAKES pipeline that makes use of the UMLSlookupannotator to perform NER (named entity recognition).  Additionally I have a .owl ontology that I have made using protege.  Essentially, what I am trying to do is to extend the UMLS ontology to include my own. However, I can't seem to find any documentation online.

If anyone here has experience trying to do something like this either with UIMA or with cTAKES and could point me in the direction of any resources that would really be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I am encountering a similar situation, have you found any solution/suggestion ??